# Como faço para obter os valores de um date no formato "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" e comparar com data do sistema após defini-lo neste mesmo formato?

Tags: java, datetime, objetos, comparação

Eu queria fazer uma comparação entre a data contida no objeto hora1 com a data do sistema, como posso fazer?

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class MainTarefas {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date horaMarcada = new Date(1,1,1,1,1);
        Date horaAtual = new Date();
        System.out.println(horaMarcada.compareTo(horaAtual));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução genérica para comparar quaisquer partes de uma data com apenas um parâmetro poderia ser assim:

```java
public class ComparadorData {

    public static boolean compareByPattern(Date d1, Date d2, String pattern) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        return sdf.format(d1).equals(sdf.format(d2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //forma mais adequada para criar uma data especificando ano, mês dia, hora e minuto
        //lembrando que o mês começa com zero (janeiro) e vai até 11 (dezembro)
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(2014, 11, 30, 23, 59); // 30/12/2014 23:59
        Date horaMarcada = c.getTime();

        //hora atual
        Date horaAtual = new Date();

        //exibe resultado
        System.out.println("São Iguais? " +
                compareByPattern(horaMarcada, horaAtual, "yyyyMMddHHmm"));

    }

}
```

Comment: Funcionou, valeu!

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o método [compareTo](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29)

data1.compareTo(data2);

Comment: Embora esta forma de comparação de datas esteja correta em alguns contextos, ela não responde corretamente à pergunta, pois o método `compareTo` vai comparar os segundos e até os milissegundos e não apenas a hora atual.